# Android Accelerometer For Gaming

Tags: android, accelerometer

I'm designing a game for Android and I would like to use the accelerometer for some aspects of control.  Has anyone come across a tutorial or example for something like this?

Comment: Don't know if they're exact duplicates, but these should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059839/how-to-build-a-sensor-simulator-for-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198982/how-to-do-gesture-recognition-using-accelerometers

Answer (score 7):

AndEngine supports easy access to the acelerometer

You call this method to enable the Accelerometer with a listener:

```
this.enableAccelerometerSensor(this);
```

and this is how you react on changes of the accelerometer:

```
@Override
public void onAccelerometerChanged(final AccelerometerData pAccelerometerData) {
    this.mPhysicsWorld.setGravity(new Vector2(pAccelerometerData.getY(), pAccelerometerData.getX()));
}
```

(Taken from: http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/PhysicsExample.java )

Best Regards,

Nicolas

Comment: There are lots of objects on my screen like (Ball, Sticks, Windows etc) but i want only sticks can be move using accelerometer. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to checkout this [open sourced marble game](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Amazed/src/com/example/amazed). at google code.